# How to redirect maven build test errors in a specific file?

Tags: java, spring, logging, cucumber, test-framework

I need to redirect maven build test errors (including full exception) which I see in Jenkins build console into a specific file using cucumber+java+spring?

I've tried to use redirectTestOutputToFile and useFile but it outputs only errors into separate file, not the one I need.

Comment: Why not start with something simple like `mvn test >test.log 2>&1`?

Comment: Maven is running on Jenkins CI not from console

Comment: Ah OK. But you *could* run it from the console ..?